# Javaのコードがわからない

Tags: java

```
name(new int[]{{0x8140, 0x829E}, // ひらがな以外の文字
　　　　　　　　{0x82F2, 0x84FC}  // ひらがな以外
       　　　　 });

0x8140    和字間隔　　　　   0x829E    　プラス記号とマイナス記号
0x82F2    濁点付き平仮名う   0x84FC　　// 不明
```

`{0x8140, 0x829E}{0x82F2, 0x84FC}` がどうしてひらがな以外の文字を表すのか分からないです。
こちらは0x8140から0x829Eというように範囲を示しているのでしょうか？

これらのコードがどういう意味を持つのかがわからないのですが、教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"shift-jis 文字コード"といったキーワードで検索すると、次のようなページがヒットするかと思います。

- https://seiai.ed.jp/sys/text/java/shiftjis_table.html

個々にある表を見るとわかりますが、
「ぁ」を表すシフトJISのコードは`829F`です。
同様に「ん」は`82F1`です。

それぞれ質問文に登場する `0x829E` の次、 `0x82F2` の前なので、
シフトJISの文字コードの範囲を指定する意図のコード片かと思われます。

---

質問文中のコードはJavaとして成立していない、かつ断片的であるので推測を多分に含みますが、
`name`メソッドの引数に指定するのは入力不可能文字のシフトJISコードの範囲であり、その範囲の指定方法は、

- 禁止文字コードの範囲の開始を0番目の要素に、禁止文字コードの範囲の終了を1番目に設定した要素数2の配列

を配列にしたものです。

Comment: 0x8140    和字間隔ではなく、分解して考えるんですね！

Comment: {0x8140, 0x829E}があ～んのように～からという範囲をしていする書き方になっているのはこの ","が”～”を意味するというような文法てきなものでしょうか？

Comment: あからんを指定するには、配列みたいなものを用意して範囲を指定するしかわからなかったのですが、、

Comment: 「この ","が”～”を意味するというような文法てきなものでしょうか？」については、そうではないです。`name`メソッドの中で、そのようにみなして処理しているだけです。`name`メソッドの詳細も見てみるとよいかと思います。(もう少し正しいコードや`name`メソッドの詳細が質問文に追記できるのであれば、回答できることも増えるかも知れません。現状ですと推測で書けるのはこの程度です)